# How to find a Craigslist ad URL from the anonymous relay e-mail address?

Tags: craigslist

How can I find the **Craigslist post URL** from an anonymous email responding to that post?

How do I perform a reverse lookup from this information:

> craigslist has implemented 2-way email relay to help stop spam and scams.
>
> When replying to a post you'll see an address like:
> `abcde-0123456789@sale.craigslist.org`
>
> When answering an email you'll see an address like:
> `rcc9la26d7534400a6a03514c34f9200@reply.craigslist.org`
>
> Use your email program as you normally would.
>
> PLEASE NOTE: The “real name” field (e.g. Jane Doe) in your email program is passed through to the recipient. Any contact information in the body of your message will pass through unaltered.
>
> https://www.craigslist.org/about/help/email-relay

In order to retrieve the **original post URL**?

Can I pop `abcde-0123456789@sale.craigslist.org` or even just the `abcde-0123456789` slug into a search engine of some sort?

I don't see any such search option on Craigslist itself.